# matching color tones and lights of 2 images with photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, color-match

I'll use cartoon or cartoon-like images in my site. In my some articles I'll have more than 1 images that is related to the content. After finding the suitable images I want these images to match by means of colors and density of light they use.

So, for example there are 2 images below:

[image]

[image]

My favorite one is the upper one (Rosa Parks). Pastel, soft.

The lower one (I name it justice) is as you see is dark and not-soft.

My aim is to resemble the "justice" image to "Rosa Parks" image as much as possible by means of color tones and light density.

**Q1)** How can I achieve this with photoshop? (I have version 6)

OR

**Q2)** I couldn't find a satisfying tutorial on web so since I don't know the technical terms of photoshop world I used wrong search keys. If this question needs a very huge answer, can you provide me correct searching keywords and/or some links you know

thanks in advance
regards

Comment: If there were a magic button to transform the illustrative work of one artist to match the illustrative work of another artist, all artists would be superfluous. You can't, as a third party, mimic style across illustrations in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what your question is. If you just what the colour scheme transfering over to the line art, you could get lucky by using the match color option. But it isn't always going to work. Select the line art layer, then open match color panel. (Image...Adjustments...Match Color). In source box select your justice image location. This can be in the same file as your lineart or a seperate open file. Then select the right layer for this. Have a play with the luminance to get the desired results. Click OK will then recolour the image using the colour scheme and blacks & white from the justice file.

[image]